# Pandoc and LaTeX - Greek Hyphenation Problem

Tags: greek, pandoc

I am trying to use Pandoc with LaTeX but I have a problem with the hyphenation for greek, or more specifically the lack thereof. Having activated `polyglossia` I don't see why it doesn't just work. As a side note, english hyphenation works normally, but that doesn't say a lot. I am using `xelatex` as a backend, so what is the problem?

***MWE***

```
---
mainfont: FiraCode-Regular.otf
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{fontspec}
    - \usepackage{polyglossia}
    - \setdefaultlanguage{greek}
---

# Text

This is text.

Αυτό είναι κείμενο.
```

Comment: Can you please show the generated TeX file?

Comment: @egreg Of course, but how?

Comment: At least, show the command line you use.

Comment: @egreg `pandoc --pdf-engine=xelatex test.md -o test.pdf`

Comment: I found out how to get the `.tex` file (just use `-o test.tex`). The sample file obviously cannot show problems with hyphenation, but if I modify the Greek sentence to be `\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}Αυτό είναι κείμενο.}` I get `Αυτό εί-ναι κεί-μενο.` (in separate lines, of course). This means no issue with hyphenation, I guess.

Comment: @egreg I run the same and it just places every word in a new line with no hyphenation. I run Pandoc/LaTeX inside a  Docker container so I guess this is the issue.

Comment: have you installed the Greek hyphenation patterns (texlive does not install all languages by default)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No I didn't.  I thought you had to do something like that for `babel` not for `polyglossia` too. Searching online I found that `polyglossia` was taking care of it.

Comment: the hyphenation patterns need to be downloaded and compiled into the format at the time xelatex format is made, it is not something that can be done by any package loaded into a document.

Comment: what do `tlmgr info hyphen-greek` (or `tlmgr info hyphen-ancientgreek`) report?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `texlive.image: tlpkg/tlpsrc/hyphen-ancientgreek.tlpsrc babel: texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/locale/grc/babel-ancientgreek.tex`

Comment: I was expecting an answer like `installed:   Yes` (or `installed:   No`) ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This runs inside a Docker container so it is a bit more complicated! :P

Answer (score 2):

I cannot test with FiraCode-Regular.otf, but this work with `xelatex` and Liberation as  greek font and as main font (see comments in code):

[image: mww]

```
---
documentclass: article
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: xelatex
mainfont: Liberation Serif
sansfont: Liberation Sans
header-includes:
- \usepackage{polyglossia}
- \newfontfamily\greekfont{Liberation Serif}
- \newfontfamily\greekfontsf{Liberation Sans}
- \setdefaultlanguage{english}
- \setotherlanguage{greek}
---

# Text

This is text. Αυτό είναι κείμενο  <!-- no with default main font -->   
\mbox{\sffamily This is text. Αυτό είναι κείμενο}  <!-- no with default main sans font -->  
This is text. \textgreek{Αυτό είναι κείμενο}    
This is text. \textgreek{\sffamily{Αυτό είναι κείμενο}}   
This is text.   

\selectlanguage{greek} 

Αυτό είναι κείμενο. <!-- also with default font -->
```